# how to use azurewebsites root url for my blob storage file url using Azure CDN?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage, cdn, azure-cdn

I have created blob storage and uploaded my `index.html` file.

file url looks like - `https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/demopage.html`

I have one webapp `https://mycompanydemo.azurewebsites.net/`

I'm rendering index.html from blob storage to my webapp using iframe.

After render I want to show url expected output -

`https://mycompanydemo.azurewebsites.net/demopage.html`

for this i have created cdn endpoint and configure it inside blob storage.

still not sure how can I achieve above url result . I tried to configure CNAME/DNS setting as well but while adding custom domain inside CDN endpoint as `mycompanydemo.azurewebsites.net`

It gives error like

> we could not finf DNS record for `mycompanydemo.azurewebsites.net`
> that points to `newcdn.azureedge.net`

As I mention my end goal is `https://mycompanydemo.azurewebsites.net/demopage.html` which shows demopage.html from blob storage.

Comment: Please check this it may help you : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/572469/cdn-endpoint-not-recognize-my-dns-record-when-sett.html

Comment: Thank you is that I can achieve same using application gateway ?

Comment: Hey @Neo had it solved your problem else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

•   Yes, you can surely use the ‘index.html’ blob file in the Azure CDN endpoint. For that purpose, you will have to create an Azure CDN profile and an endpoint accordingly as stated by you in your post. Since, you have created the said required and tried to configure an Azure hosted domain to map to the Azure CDN endpoint, you will have to create some DNS records for that domain to redirect or point to the Azure CDN endpoint created and display the blob file intended to serve.

Also, you want to redirect requests to this webapp page URL ‘https://mycompanydemo.azurewebsites.net/demopage.html’ of yours to the Azure CDN endpoint where the blob file is hosted, i.e., ‘https://newcdn.azureedge.net’. For that purpose, you will have to create **CNAME DNS record** for the ‘mycompanydemo.azurewebsites.net’ webapp page subdomain to the ‘newcdn.azureedge.net’ Azure CDN endpoint domain. Since both are **DNS labels without a published public IP address** and owned by Azure DNS, you will have to create a **private DNS zone** in Azure in which you should be able to create the required CNAME records and create an alias DNS redirect to the desired Azure FQDN as below: -

[image: Azure DNS zones]

Once the above shown has been done, you will not further get the below error that you are encountering, i.e., ‘we could not find DNS record for ‘mycompanydemo.azurewebsites.net’ that points to ‘newcdn.azureedge.net’’.

•   Also, you cannot achieve the above using application gateway as said by you in your comment because you want to redirect the traffic to the Azure CDN endpoint through the Azure webapp URL but application gateway acts as a load balancer to the incoming traffic and distributes the traffic according to the defined rules to the backend endpoints. Thus, you will need to use Azure DNS zone for this purpose.

Kindly refer to the documentation links below for more information regarding the above: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-add-to-web-app

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain?tabs=azure-dns%2Cazure-portal%2Cazure-portal-cleanup